# GraphQL SDL enum types

Tags: enums, graphql, graphql-js

We have a bunch of enum types defined in an SDL and they work great for queries and mutations. 
In the resolvers section these are mapped to the strings which represent those enums in the back end.

For example in the SDL we have :

```
enum WRRole {
    USER
    PROVIDER
    SUPPORT
    ADMIN
    SUPER_ADMIN
    GUEST
}
```

And in the resolvers section we have :

```
WRRole: {
   USER: 'user',
   PROVIDER: 'provider',
   SUPPORT: 'support',
   ADMIN: 'admin',
   SUPER_ADMIN: 'super admin',
   GUEST: 'guest'
},
```

The resolvers match the enum values defined in the nodejs backend using Mongoose where the field is defined as :

```
...
roles: {
  type: [
    {
      type: String,
      enum: ['user', 'provider', 'support', 'admin', 'super admin', 'guest']
    }
  ],
  default: ['user']
},
...
```

The issue we have with GraphQL enums is that we cannot introspect the enums and get back the mappings using GraphQL introspection....

This causes issues with constructing UI's where we want to present the user with a dropdown list of these as options. The SDL enum values such as SUPER_USER are great for the keys but we want to display the actual backend mapped value to the use to select from.

This is just one example of many enums we have. Many of the mapped values consist of multiple words that have spaces between or words containing characters not allowed in the SDL enum value such as "super admin" in this case.

So my question is... How are you all handling stuff like this without having to repeat yourself or add more code to the front end to map these to more useful meaningful names for presentation ????

The order cannot be guaranteed to match the defined order of the enums in the backend so adding to the backend model enums would seriously mess up any assumptions that SUPER_USER actually maps to "super user" even though the resolver knows this.

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there isn't a perfect solution for this IMHO
there are a couple of ways I would approach this problem

1. **Elegant way** 
   You can add to your graphql schema a query that receives the `Enum` name
   like so (in `SDL` ) :

   ```
   type Query {
        getEnumValues(enumName: String!): [EnumKeyValue!]!
   }

   type EnumKeyValue {
        key: String!
        value: String
   }
   ```

   this requires you to change your backend code a bit, for instance I would change the `Enum` resolver to get it's data from an object like so:

   ```
   const enums = {
       WRRole: {
           USER: 'user',
           PROVIDER: 'provider',
           ...
       }
   };

   const enumResolver = {
       WRRole: {
          USER: enums.WRRole.USER,
          PROVIDER: enums.WRRole.PROVIDER,
          ...
       }
   };
   ```

   and then the resolver for `getEnumValues` would look like:

   ```
   const queryResolvers = {
         getEnumValues(source, args) {
              const enumKey = args.enumName;

              // enums is the same enums object from the previous example
              return Object.keys(enums[enumKey]).map(key => ({ 
                   key,
                   value: enums[enumKey][key] 
              }))

         }
   };
   ```
2. **Dirty, Abusive but quick**
   Another possible way, that is a bit abusive is to add a description on the `Enum` value
   so your `Enum` `SDL` would like:

   ```
       enum WRRole {
         # user
         USER
         # provider
         PROVIDER
         # support
         SUPPORT
         # admin
         ADMIN
         # super admin
         SUPER_ADMIN
         # guest
         GUEST
       }
   ```

   And then you can get the mapping between the key and the description with the following query:

   ```
       {
         __type(name: "WRRole") {
           enumValues {
             description
             name
           }
         }
       }
   ```

Comment: Funny enough I originally tried your "Dirty, Abusive but quick" solution but the result for description is always null in this case.

Comment: I am working on another solution at the moment as your preferred solution is way over complicated due to the fact we have a large number of enums to work with.

Comment: @user1790230 why is the result null? (are you using schema stitching?)
have a look at this example, should work
https://launchpad.graphql.com/5507l37qw9

I'm curious to hear what other solution you have in mind?

Comment: Yes. We are stitching 4 schemas together. Two of these are remote schemas and the other 2 are local to our services. It appears that NONE of the comments on enum fields are retained. All other types have their comments left intact and these can be introspected just fine. Once I get a little time I will work on the more generic solution I have in mind. That's not to say it will work but well give it a go and I'll update this post with the answer then.

Comment: @user1790230 If you're using graphql-tools then there is a new version ^3.1.0
that has a fix for the issue with enums descriptions not being retained,
take a look here: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/pull/898/

Comment: Thanks for that info Daniel. I have just upgraded to 3.1.1 and comments on enums are now working. This will save me a lot of effort and as such I have marked your answer as accepted. Thanks